# How to setup Django + RabbitMQ + Celery with Docker?

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq, celery

I'm trying to setup my Django app to have push notification functionality. For scheduling notifications I'm trying to use Celery, for the message broker I chose RabbitMQ. My app is running in Docker containers and I'm struggling to get the RabbitMQ to work. I get an error message `Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 111] Connection refused.` when running `docker-compose up`. Here are my `celery` and `rabbitmq3` services from my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
celery:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
    command: celery -A test_celery worker -l info
    volumes:
      - .:/test_celery
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    depends_on:
      - app
      - rabbitmq3
  
rabbitmq3:
  container_name: "rabbitmq"
  image: rabbitmq:3-management-alpine
  ports:
    - 5672:5672
    - 15672:15672
```

In my `test_celery` -app I have a file called `celery.py` which contains the following:

```
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'test_celery.settings')

app = Celery('test_celery')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

And finally, in my `settings.py` I have this: `CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://localhost'`.

Should I define the `CELERY_BROKER_URL` somehow different? Is there something wrong with my docker-compose file? Would appreciate any help with this, what is wrong with my setup?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this should do the trick

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL=amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq3:5672/
```

if you have a vhost on rabbit

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL=amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq3:5672/vhost
```

if it does not work check the console of the rabbit container for clues

Comment: Also sometimes celery can try to connect to rabbitmq when rabbitmq is not ready, so I wait for celery to retry until it's connected

Answer (score 0):

In **settings.py** define:

```
RABBITMQ = {
    "PROTOCOL": "amqp", # in prod change with "amqps"
    "HOST": os.getenv("RABBITMQ_HOST", "localhost"),
    "PORT": os.getenv("RABBITMQ_PORT", 5672),
    "USER": os.getenv("RABBITMQ_USER", "guest"),
    "PASSWORD": os.getenv("RABBITMQ_PASSWORD", "guest"),
}

CELERY_BROKER_URL = f"{RABBITMQ['PROTOCOL']}://{RABBITMQ['USER']}:{RABBITMQ['PASSWORD']}@{RABBITMQ['HOST']}:{RABBITMQ['PORT']}"
```